# Copy parameters as constant values?

Tags: python, cntk

I trained an speech model with lots of data (using CNTK), and need to adapt it to a low resource language. As the amount of data in target language is too small, I decide to use first three layers of original model (as constants) and append two feed forward layers on top. I can not find a clear way to do that.

To simplify things, assume my original model is:

```
model1 = Sequential([Recurrence(LSTM(1024, use_peepholes=True)), Dense(40), Recurrence(LSTM(1024, use_peepholes=True)), Dense(256), Dense(num_classes1)])
```

and I need to my low resource model be something like:

```
model2 = Sequential([Recurrence(LSTM(1024, use_peepholes=True)), Dense(40), Recurrence(LSTM(1024, use_peepholes=True)), Dense(128), Dense(num_classes2)])
```

How I can copy parameters of first three layers of model1 to model2 as constant values (not to update during training process of model2)?

Answer (score 2):

You can clone a network and freeze the parameters. The documentation can be found here:

https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/graph.html?highlight=clone%20freeze#cntk.ops.functions.CloneMethod

You can find example here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/77154a7f7288d4b119e415039be6471565fceccf/Examples/Image/TransferLearning/TransferLearning.py

Comment: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
First link is not working.